# why is this form being submitted?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `html` page. If the user clicks the button `quit` it's expected to forward to a `Goodbye.html` page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Answers</title>
</head>
   <script type="javascript/text">    
    function quit()
    {
        window.location = "www.google.com";      
    }    
   </script>
<body>
  <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <h1>Answers<br></h1>

    <h2><font color="#0033CC">Instant Psychology</font></h2>

    <blockquote>
      <h1><font color="#CC6600">Perfectionist<br></font></h1>
    </blockquote>

    <h2><font color="#CC0000">Instant Geography</font></h2>

    <blockquote>
      <h1><font color="#009900">Hawaii<br></font></h1>
    </blockquote>

    <h2><font color="#660033">Instant Gastronomy</font></h2>

    <blockquote>
      <h1><font color="#FF66FF">Souffle<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="another" value="Do Another One" onclick="doanother();">
      <input type="submit" name="quit" value="Quit" onclick="quit();"></font></h1>
    </blockquote>
  </form>


</body><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css,"></html>
```

Why is the page going to the initial page then?

Comment: Why would window.location = www.google.com be expected to go to a goodbye.html page?

Comment: you could change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the form from submitting by using `return false;`

```
function quit()
{
    window.location = "www.google.com";  
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not true. You need to also change the HTML to `onclick="return quit();"` if you use this solution...

Answer (score 2):

If you want the buttons to do whatever function you have created and not to use their default submit functionality then you should change your code from:

```
<input type="submit">
```

to:

```
<input type="button">
```

The `type="submit"` submits a form by default. You could also just use:

```
return false;
```

in your JavaScript function to prevent it from performing the default submit action.

Comment: Only using `return false;` in the function won't stop the default submit action, unless you also used `onclick="return quit();"`. Now, that differs from using actual event listeners, not inline event handlers. Using `return false;` in a listener will prevent default behavior.